# AWS PHP SDK issue with Dynamodb WriteRequestBatch

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am experimenting with WriteRequestBatch from AWS SDK for Dynamodb. Below is my code. Everything works except the WriteRequestBatch part. I have no clue why, and was wondering if the community could help me out here. What might I be doing wrong? I have tried googling and searching here and found only 8 other questions that could be related but unfortunately were of no help.

[This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-dynamodb.html#using-the-writerequestbatch) is where I started from.

```
$ddb_client = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'key' => 'my_key',
    'secret' => 'my_secret'
));

$ddb_client->createTable(array(
    'TableName' => 'my_table',
    'AttributeDefinitions' => array(
        array(
            'AttributeName' => 'id',
            'AttributeType' => 'S'
        ),
        array(
            'AttributeName' => 'ns',
            'AttributeType' => 'S'
        )
    ),
    'KeySchema' => array(
        array(
            'AttributeName' => 'id',
            'KeyType'       => 'HASH'
        ),
        array(
            'AttributeName' => 'ns',
            'KeyType'       => 'RANGE'
        )
    ),
    'ProvisionedThroughput' => array(
        'ReadCapacityUnits'  => 10,
        'WriteCapacityUnits' => 10
    )
));

$response = $ddb_client->putItem(array(
    "TableName" => "my_table",
    "Item" => array(
        "id" => array("S" => "exp_id"),
        "ns" => array("S" => "exp_ns"),
        "version" => array("N" => "0"),
    ),
));

$item = $response['Item'];
$item['version']['N'] = '1';

$put_batch = WriteRequestBatch::factory($ddb_client);
$put_request = new PutRequest(
    array(
        "Item" => $item,
        "Expected" => array(
            "version" => array(
                "ComparisonOperator" => "EQ",
                "AttributeValueList" => array(
                    array("N" => "0")
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
    "my_table"
);
$putBatch->add($put_request);
$putBatch->flush();
```

This works instead of WriteRequestBatch. I will just have to manage batches to put myself than use WriteRequestBatch doing it for me:

```
$response = $ddb_client->batchWriteItem(array(
    "RequestItems" => array(
        "my_table" => array(
            array(
                "PutRequest" => array(
                    "Item" => $item,
                    "Expected" => array(
                        "version" => array(
                            "ComparisonOperator" => "EQ",
                            "AttributeValueList" => array(
                                array("S" => "0")
                            )
                        ),
                    ),
                )
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [answer by Geek Stocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309956/aws-php-sdk-issue-with-dynamodb-writerequestbatch/27314558#27314558) is incomplete, but still helpful. One thing you can do handle the asynchronous aspects of the `CreateTable` operation is to use a [*Waiter*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-waiters.html):

```
$ddb_client->createTable(array('TableName' => 'my_table', ... ));
$ddb_client->waitUntil('TableExists', array('TableName' => 'my_table'));
```

**However**, there is also a problem with how you are using the `WriteRequestBatch` class. When you create a `PutRequest`, you must pass in the item, not a whole set of `PutItem` parameters. The `WriteRequestBatch` is an abstraction over DynamoDB's [`BatchWriteItem` operation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html), which does not allow things like the `Expected` parameter. If you want to do that, then you need to use individual `PutItem`/`UpdateItem`/`DeleteItem` requests.

Here is a modified version of your usage of `WriteRequestBatch` that is correct:

```
$putBatch = WriteRequestBatch::factory($ddb_client);
$putBatch->add(new PutRequest($item, 'my_table'));
// ADD MORE...
// ...
// ...
$putBatch->flush();
```

[Here is another example of using the `WriteRequestBatch` from the SDK's User Guide.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-dynamodb.html#using-the-writerequestbatch)

---

**EDIT**: One more *complete* example that works that I just tested, that shows the difference between versions prior to 2.7.0 and afterwards

```
use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;
use Aws\DynamoDb\Model\BatchRequest\WriteRequestBatch;
use Aws\DynamoDb\Model\BatchRequest\PutRequest;
use Aws\DynamoDb\Model\Item;

$client = DynamoDbClient::factory([/* ... */]);
$batch = WriteRequestBatch::factory($client);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 55; $i++) {
    // FOR ANY SDK VERSION
    // (NOTE: Does not support new M, L, BOOL, and NULL types)
    $item = Item::fromArray(['id' => $i, 'data' => "foo{$i}"]);
    // FOR SDK >= 2.7
    $item = ['id' => ['N' => $i], 'data' => ['S' => "foo{$i}"]];

    $batch->add(new PutRequest($item, 'my-table'));
}
$batch->flush();
```

Comment: Actually Jeremy, the code in the docs you reference is quite broken. Try a direct copy/paste and you'll see what I mean. Throws "Argument 1 passed to Aws\DynamoDb\Model\BatchRequest\PutRequest::__construct() must be an instance of Aws\DynamoDb\Model\Item, array given...<snip>"  Perhaps the API is ahead of the docs?  Hmmm...still working on this.

Comment: @Jeremy I don't know if you noticed **[This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-dynamodb.html#using-the-writerequestbatch) is where I started from.**, This points to AWS SDK link.

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? If it's prior to 2.7, then I think you must use the `Item` class. Starting from 2.7.0, you can make it work with either the `Item` class or just a regular array. I have added a complete example to my answer that shows usage in either version.

Comment: @Jeremy Nice job there - I just tested your code through and it works nicely. Not sure what version of the SDK I inherited from the previous guy though. I am looking for a way to tell...

Comment: `echo \Aws\Common\Aws::VERSION;` :-)

Comment: @JeremyLindblom Thank you for confirming it for me that WriteRequestBatch doesn't allow parameters like Expected. I did find that through looking at the AWS SDK code, but I wasn't sure about it as I am new to PHP. I'll accept this as an answer, since it did solve my problem! I am able to use Expected with batchWriteItem method. I guess I will just have to make batches on my side rather than SDK do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because you currently do not have any "try / catch" error handling around your code you are likely not getting good information on your error.

I placed try/catch blocks on your code and found that the table creates just fine but that the call to putItem fails for the following reason: **Requested resource not found**

When you create a table it is NOT immediately available. You have to pause until it becomes available. [This paragraph of the AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.DynamoDb.DynamoDbClient.html#_createTable) explains this nicely:

> CreateTable is an asynchronous operation. Upon receiving a CreateTable request, DynamoDB immediately returns a response with a TableStatus of CREATING . After the table is created, DynamoDB sets the TableStatus to ACTIVE . You can perform read and write operations only on an ACTIVE table. You can use the DescribeTable API to check the table status.

Once you add the call to DescribeTable like it shows, you should be good.

Comment: I don't know if you noticed it but **Everything works except the WriteRequestBatch part**. I do have try catch block around the WriteRequestBatch part in my actual code. This code here is a simplified example I created based on my actual code which is suffering from the same issue.

Comment: @bagi Many times OP's think they have a problem in one part of their code when actually its something they don't yet see. No, I didn't notice because the code you posted breaks well before the WriteRequestBatch portion. Also, your code looked right according to the documentation.

Comment: I should've mentioned that. Sorry about that :)

Comment: No problems. Jeremy's answer is quite good. Glad you got helped.